# Ruby on Rails 7: Validate collection_check_boxes array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

In Rails, I have a model called `Post` with a field called `columns`. The user can select which columns are to be displayed. I do this using the following line of code in my form:

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes(:columns, { "Title": "title", "Body": "body" }, :last, :first) %>
```

I use this so that I can simply store the columns the user wants to display in an array in my database. The problem is that I need to validate this array to make sure that only the allowed columns can be selected. To do this, I have the following validation for my post model:

```
validate :validate_columns

def validate_columns
  permitted = [ "title", "body" ]

  unless columns.is_a?(Array) && columns.all?{ |c| permitted.include?(c) }
    errors.add(:columns, :invalid)
  end
end
```

This works well for only allowing the wanted columns, however now I cannot submit the form without getting an error since the collection_check_boxes helper automatically adds an empty field to the array to handle the case when no checkboxes are selected. The problem is that this fails my validation.

I have already read about the `include_hidden: false` option for collection_check_boxes, however if I use that, the user cannot deselect all columns.

So, does anybody have any ideas on how I could solve this or if this approach is even viable at all?

**Edit:**

These are my strong params in my controller:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, columns: [])
end
```

And this is my migration:

```
def change
  create_table :posts do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body
    t.string :columns, array: true, default: []

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

Comment: `columns = columns.select { |c| !c&.strip&.empty?}.compact` before your unless statement to remove the empty entry which you likely do not want to save anyway

Comment: @dbugger Okay, thank you, this sounds like what I need. The problem is that when I implement that I get the error: private method `select' called for nil:NilClass.

Comment: That means your columns attribute is nil - do a check and exit the method if that’s the case

Comment: @dbugger Hmm, that's weird. When I call `p columns` in the line before it, it's not nil and contains all the columns like expected. Calling `p columns.class` also reveals that it is in fact an array

Comment: Don't know what to tell you - typo?, name conflict?

Comment: @dbugger I solved the issue now by writing this.columns = columns.select… still a weird error though, since it does not occur when I assign the value of columns.select to a different variable (e.g. abc = columns.select…)